# ¿How to send an email in different languages depends on the language of the receiver?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I need to send some emails (same code and messages) but only with the correct language. If the customers are from USA the email was on american english, if they are from UK in GB english...the same for canadian french, spanish from spain, italian, etc.

What kind of code we need to use? or, What we need to use?

Sorry guys but we are a little dummies with this.

[the email we want to sent in multiple languages](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-uWoLNMMby4TWwpwMOw9Yr5uNpK6YiZC/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a language and country attribute to the subscriber data / or to the sending data extension.

Then create one email with multiple dynamic content blocks with rules which look like language = en and country = USA if this is true take the content block with American English, if language = en and country = GBR then take the content block with British English.

For this you don’t need any code, just the data and dynamic content blocks.

Comment: Ook Johannes!! I want to try right now. But it's a hard work to make all the Dynamic Blocks hahahahahaha...but if this works, it's worth it!! Thanks!!